# Parse Data from OPENJSON()

Tags: open-json

Here is my string:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON ('{"data":{"CAD":1.3480102032}}')
WITH ( Rate VARCHAR(200) '$.data')
```

I need to extract the value 1.3480102032

Sorry, new to this!
The result from what I get is NULL.
Please help.

Comment: Object members can be accessed using dot-notation `WITH (cad FLOAT '$.data.CAD')` [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#with_clause-1)

Comment: I need to put this value into a SQL table. I tried WITH (cad FLOAT '$data.CAD') but it did not work.

Comment: This is a daily exchange rate. I need to show the user in my Access front end what today's exchange rate is.

Comment: K! I got it to work:
 select * from OPENJSON ('{"data":{"CAD":1.3480102032}}')
 WITH (Rate FLOAT '$.data."CAD"')

Answer (score 1):

```
    select * from OPENJSON ('{"data":{"CAD":1.3480102032}}')
WITH (Rate FLOAT '$.data."CAD"')
```

CAD needed to be put in quotes as it is a string.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**